# How can I concatenate an array of DataFrames in Julia?

Tags: dataframe, julia

I am trying to reduce an array of `DataFrames` I have down into one `DataFrame` by concatenating a common column in each `DataFrame`.

This is an example of what I have tried so far:

```
using DataFrames

samples=[DataFrame(x=[1,2,3],y=[1,2,3]),DataFrame(x=[4,5,6],y=[4,5,6]),DataFrame(x=[7,8,9],y=[7,8,9])]

hcat(select.(samples,:y)[1],select.(samples,:y)[2],select.(samples,:y)[3],makeunique=true) #this works

hcat(select.(samples,:y),makeunique=true)    #this doesn't
```

The problem with the former solution is that the `samples` array could be arbitrarily long depending on the data.

It seems that `makeunique` is only defined for `DataFrame` methods; do I need to define a new `DataFrames` `hcat` method? Or can I somehow "type" out each `DataFrame` so that `hcat` interprets it as a list of `DataFrames`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[The `DataFrames` package defines an `hcat` function](https://juliadata.github.io/DataFrames.jl/stable/lib/functions/#Base.hcat) that takes a variable number of `DataFrame` objects.  All you have to do is unpack the `Array{DataFrame,2}` that is returned by `select.` with the [`...` operator](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/faq/#The-two-uses-of-the-...-operator:-slurping-and-splatting-1), like so:

```
julia> hcat(select.(samples, :y)..., makeunique=true)
3×3 DataFrame
│ Row │ y     │ y_1   │ y_2   │
│     │ Int64 │ Int64 │ Int64 │
├─────┼───────┼───────┼───────┤
│ 1   │ 1     │ 4     │ 7     │
│ 2   │ 2     │ 5     │ 8     │
│ 3   │ 3     │ 6     │ 9     │
```